# Add Watermark to PDF using iTextSharp Not working for Image PDF C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am using the below code to add a watermark in PDF. It is working fine for normal text PDF. If it contains images watermark is not visible.

```
public void AddWatermarkPdf()
      {
          PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("SimpleArabic.pdf");
          PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() 
         + "Out.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
         iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("WaterMarkDoc.png");
          img.SetAbsolutePosition(-200, -50);
          PdfContentByte waterMark;
          for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
          {
            Rectangle pagesize = pdfReader.GetCropBox(pageIndex);
            waterMark = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(pageIndex);
            waterMark.AddImage(img);
          }
          pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
          pdfStamper.Close();
     }
```

Watermark has to apply even if images are in PDF.

Comment: Your code doesn't add a watermark, it adds an image behind any existing content. Any opaque object (like another image) displayed above your image will hide it. The only way to make your image appear below another image would be to make the existing image transparent

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to add a watermark: under the existing content or on top of the existing content. For your intended purpose the best way would be to add the watermark on top of the PDFs contents with the watermark set to a lower opacity.

This is a Java code sample, but can easily be transcribed:

```java
protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontProgramFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA));
    PdfCanvas over = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getFirstPage());
    over.setFillColor(ColorConstants.BLACK);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This watermark is added ON TOP OF the existing content")
            .setFont(font).setFontSize(15);
    new Canvas(over, pdfDoc, pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize())
            .showTextAligned(p, 297, 500, 1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
    p = new Paragraph("This TRANSPARENT watermark is added ON TOP OF the existing content")
            .setFont(font).setFontSize(15);
    over.saveState();
    PdfExtGState gs1 = new PdfExtGState();
    gs1.setFillOpacity(0.5f);
    over.setExtGState(gs1);
    new Canvas(over, pdfDoc, pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize())
             .showTextAligned(p, 297, 450, 1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
    over.restoreState();
    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

Source: This is very thoroughly explained on the iText Knowledge Base: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-add-a-watermark-to-a-page-with-an-opaque-image

Edit:

This is the C# example for the iText 5 version you are using:

```
 public class TransparentWatermark 
    {
        public static readonly String DEST = "results/sandbox/stamper/transparent_watermark.pdf";
        public static readonly String SRC = "../../../resources/pdfs/hero.pdf";

        public static void Main(String[] args) 
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
            file.Directory.Create();
            
            new TransparentWatermark().ManipulatePdf(DEST);
        }

        protected void ManipulatePdf(String dest) 
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest));
            PdfCanvas under = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.GetFirstPage().NewContentStreamBefore(), new PdfResources(), pdfDoc);
            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA));
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("This watermark is added UNDER the existing content")
                    .SetFont(font)
                    .SetFontSize(15);
            
            Canvas canvasWatermark1 = new Canvas(under, pdfDoc.GetDefaultPageSize())
                    .ShowTextAligned(paragraph, 297, 550, 1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
            canvasWatermark1.Close();
            PdfCanvas over = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.GetFirstPage());
            over.SetFillColor(ColorConstants.BLACK);
            paragraph = new Paragraph("This watermark is added ON TOP OF the existing content")
                    .SetFont(font)
                    .SetFontSize(15);
            
            Canvas canvasWatermark2 = new Canvas(over, pdfDoc.GetDefaultPageSize())
                    .ShowTextAligned(paragraph, 297, 500, 1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
            canvasWatermark2.Close();
            paragraph = new Paragraph("This TRANSPARENT watermark is added ON TOP OF the existing content")
                    .SetFont(font)
                    .SetFontSize(15);
            over.SaveState();
            
            // Creating a dictionary that maps resource names to graphics state parameter dictionaries
            PdfExtGState gs1 = new PdfExtGState();
            gs1.SetFillOpacity(0.5f);
            over.SetExtGState(gs1);
            Canvas canvasWatermark3 = new Canvas(over, pdfDoc.GetDefaultPageSize())
                    .ShowTextAligned(paragraph, 297, 450, 1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
            canvasWatermark3.Close();
            over.RestoreState();
            
            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
    }
```